# Why is wave a function of volts?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

I'm looking at a beginner's book on Fourier and waves, and the very first graph shows a periodic wave where the horizontal axis is time (msec) and the vertical axis is something noted as "MAG(V)" which is "magnitude (volt)." This supposes an understanding of wave measurement I'm not familiar with, i.e., why is the wave graph depicted in terms of, as a function of volts per millisecond?

Comment: It is probably just representing an [oscilloscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope) display

Comment: Probably because what is shown is an [alternating current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current)/voltage.

Comment: Yes, but why volts? What is it about volts that makes it a good "y-axis?" Why not something else like the actual displacement in (milli-, micro-) meters?

Comment: It depends on the system. If you're looking at waves on the ocean, you use displacement. Volts is for an electrical system -- maybe you're describing an alternating current supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not volts *per* millisecond, it's volts *at* particular milliseconds.
Think of the wave as displayed on an [*oscilloscope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope).

Waves can actually be anything as a function of anything.
It's just that voltage as a function of time is a really nice example.

Of course, when you're talking about Fourier transforms, you get into *complex* numbers.
For example, you can think of a voltage waving up and down as just looking at a light on the end of a stick that is rotating in a circle.
If you look at it from the edge, you're only seeing the "real" part, the vertical part of its motion.
Keep in mind the part of it's motion that you don't see, the "imaginary" part, which you can suppose is there even if you don't see it.

Fourier transforms work in that domain, and they are super useful.

Comment: So, basically, it's probably just the fact that an oscilloscope is being used. I guess I need to learn about why an o-scope measures in terms of volts. As I, a beginner, understand volts, they are a _Spannung_, a gradient between two energy states. So when something like a periodic wave is dancing vertically as measured in volts, I'm guessing it has to do with microphone technology, i.e., the voice is transformed by the mic, then read by the o-scope?

Comment: @user78162: Sure. You could go to an electronics store and buy a cheap voltmeter. Actually, what it measures is current through the little coil attached to the needle, but there's a resistor in series, so if you want to measure voltage, it does so. The trouble with a multi-meter is the needle is mechanical and can't move very fast. An oscilloscope trace can move faster and also show you the trace over time, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody explicitly uses the proper units for amplitudes, the square root of (action divided by the product of all your axes/variables). Instead, one usually expresses this fundamental quantity using two conjugate variables. For example, if you regard a simple mechanical oscillator as a wave by looking at its status over time, the interesting quantity (action divided by time) is the sum of kinetic and potential energy. You will likely describe the oscillator in terms of the scaled square root of each, position and momentum. A simple electrical oscillator could likewise be expressed via voltage (scaled root of energy in capacitors) and current (scaled root of energy in inductors).

This is a bit of a complication because you will sometimes need the ratio of the scale factors involved (the impedance of your system). The simplification is usually used, but only implicitly: By extending the real conjugate variables to complex ones, the other variable is included as imaginary part (rescaled to match the real part). Everyone uses that but we tend not to admit to what we are doing, instead pretending that it was "imaginary," not physical (and that "physical" quantities only correspond to the real parts), etc.